# Parse: delete session after a user deletes their account

Tags: parse-platform

I'm using the Unity API.  I let a user delete their own account.  It's accomplished via `ParseUser.CurrentUser.DeleteAsync()`

I then call `ParseUser.CurrentUser.LogoutAsync();` to delete the local ParseUser object on their device.

This works, but afterwards, the now-deleted user's session is still up, buty the associated user field is now a broken link.

How can I end this session?  I tried to get a reference to the session before deleting the user via `ParseSession session = ParseSession.GetCurrentSessionAsyn()`, deleting the user, and then the session, but the `session.DeleteAsync()` fails.

Edit (clarification):
I check all `Tasks` that return from my various function calls.  I detect when things fail, and that's how I know my `ParseSession`s aren't being deleted (plus, they're showing up in Parse's CORE session list).

I just can't find a way to make sure the session is ended from the client's side.

Answer (score 0):

`DeleteAsync` returns a [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235678) Object. Try using that object to ensure that the deletion has completed prior to calling `LogoutAsync()`

Comment: I tried this.  For the logout out to succeed, the session must still exist, which makes sense - a user without a session shouldn't be able to contact the backend.  So, it seems I need to delete the session after I delete the user.  Yet I can't find a way to do this :\